# Have no any image and data after install magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I have cloned Magento 2.3 from this link to develop code and create new item
[enter link description here](https://github.com/magento/magento2)
But when I install finished, the home page looks like this

[image]

I fixed the code in folder **\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php** like this

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

But it does not have any change, still no data, no image. 
If anyone can have me this problem, it will very useful for me! Please

Answer (score 4):

You have installed without a sample data package.

It has not products.

If you want to download with a sample data package in [Magento official site](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)

Comment: thank for your answer. But when I download from  https://magento.com/tech-resources/download it does not have folder app/code, I want to clone have app/code folder as well as have full data

Comment: Hi, @kite I think it's not a stable version. It's in the development branch. So kindly download stable version in official site

Answer (score 1):

Try with add sample data:

- php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- php bin/magento cache:clean